# EMC/EMI Testing EN61000-4-6 current clamp vs EM-clamp

Tags: rf, emc, clamp

I have a question regarding the Conducted Immunity Test (EN 61000-4-6)
In the standard it is discussed that the preferred method for injection is CDN, but when that is not available one can choose between EM clamp and current clamp.
**What are the criteria to choose between current clamp and EM clamp?**
[image]

I read the standard in detail but I missed a possible explanation, can someone enlighten me.

Thanks,

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I edit my post, thanks :)

Comment: So what does the 7.6 and 7.7 say? I don't have access to this standard currently.